# getPixel returns a negative value in Android

Tags: android, image, android-image

Friends , am new to android , and am working with a project where i want some Image processing s. And when I tried to use

```
int pixels=myImageBitmap.getPixel(x,y);
```

all I am getting is some negetive values in x
Also I am trying to set some values for that pixel using

```
result.setPixel(x,y,pixels);
```

My application stopping suddenly and , after that , my log cat is looks like

```
03-06 19:52:01.731: W/dalvikvm(29185): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41036378)
03-06 19:52:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(29185): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-06 19:52:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(29185): java.lang.IllegalStateException
03-06 19:52:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(29185):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.setPixel(Bitmap.java:1045)
03-06 19:52:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(29185):    at com.example.testpro.EncodeActivity$3.onClick(EncodeActivity.java:90)
03-06 19:52:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(29185):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4147)
03-06 19:52:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(29185):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17161)
03-06 19:52:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(29185):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-06 19:52:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(29185):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-06 19:52:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(29185):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
03-06 19:52:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(29185):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
03-06 19:52:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(29185):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-06 19:52:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(29185):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-06 19:52:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(29185):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
03-06 19:52:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(29185):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
03-06 19:52:01.731: E/AndroidRuntime(29185):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Somebody please help me to get out of this error.please Thanks in advance

Comment: You should post some code to examinate...

Comment: Most likely, your x and y are out of range.

Comment: I think ,in that case the exception would have been IllegalArgumentException instead of IllegalStateException.

Answer (score 1):

> java.lang.IllegalStateException at
>   android.graphics.Bitmap.setPixel(Bitmap.java:1045)

This exception is thrown if the `bitmap` you are using is `immutable`.
[As per document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#setPixel%28int,%20int,%20int%29)

**Reason :**

```
result.setPixel(x,y);
```

Here you are trying to make change in the pixels of the bitmap. Since the bitmap is immutable,it is not allowed hence it is throwing above exception.

**Solution:**
Make a mutable copy of the bitmap.And use it.

```
myImageBitmap = myImageBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
```

For more information Refer [Android- convert imutable bitmap to mutable](http://sudarnimalan.blogspot.in/2011/09/android-convert-immutable-bitmap-into.html)

**Update :**

> when i compare the pixel values of the two bitmap images , first one
>   and the copy , i am getting different values for same pixel , why?

```
copy(Bitmap.Config config, boolean isMutable)
```

Tries to make a new bitmap based on the dimensions of the bitmap,
setting the new bitmap's config to the one specified, and then copying
the bitmap's pixels into the new bitmap. If the conversion is not
supported, or the allocator fails, then this returns NULL. [Refer this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#copy%28android.graphics.Bitmap.Config,%20boolean%29)

The bitmap configuration ([Bitmap.Config](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html)) specified in the method, describes how pixels are stored. This affects the quality (color depth) as well as the ability to display transparent/translucent colors.

And if you look at the documentation of the [getPixel()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixel%28int,%20int%29) , it returns an integer which is a colour value.

So , if the Bitmap config used for original and copied image is different, you get different values for the same pixel.

One more reason that might lead to difference in pixel value is Pre-multiplication/Non-premultiplication of pixels. [Refer this nice information from Chet Hasse.](https://plus.google.com/+ChetHaase/posts/ef6Deey6xKA)

Comment: I tried it , It works perfectly , thanks a lot. And , when i compare the pixel values of the two bitmap images , first one and the copy , i am getting different values for same pixel , why ?

Comment: I suggest you to accept it as answer..so tgat it would be useful for future users

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a mutable copy of the bitmap, and use it.

```
myImageBitmap = myImageBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
```

Check the [link](http://sudarnimalan.blogspot.com/2011/09/android-convert-immutable-bitmap-into.html) for reference.